# I can't access static variable from global component to in our component inside subscribe in angular 7

Tags: angular

i am getting undefined variable inside subscribe.

```
import { AppSetting } from '../config/app-setting';

this.api.userLogin(this.loginForm.value.emailid,this.loginForm.value.password).subscribe(
    data => {
            this.router.navigateByUrl(AppSetting.BASE_URL+'/enquiry');
        },
      error => console.log('oops', error)
    );
```

this is my global class

```
export class AppSetting {
   public static BASE_URL='http://192.168.1.144:8080/';

}
```

Comment: You have environment files to do that.

Comment: same thing seems to be working fine [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ij5fct) .did you try `console.log(AppSetting.BASE_URL)` and check what it logs to console?

Comment: am getting undefine variable.. ji

Comment: it write console but not work redirect @jitender

Comment: use `window.location.href=AppSetting.BASE_URL+'/enquiry'` instead of  `this.router.navigateByUrl(AppSetting.BASE_URL+'/enquiry');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't redirect because the router doesn't work like that. The router is internal to Angular, you don't have to provide the domain, protocole, port ... Only the path.

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/enquiry');
```

If you wish to **go to another website**, this will be

```
window.location.href = 'http://...';
```